# Google maps animation not working with setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, settimeout, setinterval

I'm developing animation with google maps API. I get some problem with setInteval and setTimeout.

Actually, In line 247 in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oynovzq4/47/) I define myFunction(see below) which calls the function fi() each 300ms to animate the marker.

```js
var myFunction = function(){
     counter= 300;
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    
    var myInterval = setInterval(fi, counter, map, marker, g);
}
```

I want that function fi() (see below) animates the marker then when it arrives to a marker it stops a while before to move. To achieve this,  I clear the setInterval ( Line 301 ) then I recall myFunction() to restart the animation after a delay using setTimeout.

```js
function fi(m, mar, l) {
        
          if (l[i].waypoint == 0) {
       
     coords=  l[i];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords.lat), parseFloat(coords.lng));
            route.getPath().push(latlng);

            moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
     
        i++;
      coords=  l[i];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords.lat), parseFloat(coords.lng));
            route.getPath().push(latlng);

            moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
     

      
    } else {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
     i++;
    setTimeout(myFunction, 500);
    
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that the animation continue after some delay but it stops.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: I see this javascript error in your fiddle:`Uncaught ReferenceError: myInterval is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `myInterval` global, and it works for me.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oynovzq4/50/)

```
var myInterval;
var myFunction = function(){
  counter= 300;
  clearInterval(myInterval);
  myInterval = setInterval(fi, counter, map, marker, g);
}
```